# why isn't the result a scalar?

Tags: matlab

i'm stuck with this error:

In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

yres(1)=((u - uc).^2) + ((y - yc).^2) -(d.^2);
 i don't understand, why this won't get a skalar?since the elements are all scalar. what should be changed to get a scalar?

best regards

edit: thanks sloede, all inputs are scalar, but i still get this error

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
same.

```
     Error in myfun (line 7)
     yres(1)=sqrt(((u - uc).^2) + ((y - yc).^2) ) -d;
    Error in fsolve (line 241)
        fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
    Error in modfsolve (line 26)
    x= fsolve(@myfun,x0,options,uc,d,spacing_amplitude,spacing_width);
    Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE
    cannot continue.*
```

Comment: Just before the line that is giving the problem could you insert the command `whos yres u uc y yc d`, and report the output? There is definitely a problem with either your input variables or the variable you are assigning to, and the `whos` command will allow you to see the properties of these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "." before an operator means that the following operation should be applied element-wise and not on the vector as a whole. Thus

```
a = b.^2
```

will give you as a result all elements of *b* squared and saved back to *a*. Therefore, in your code statement above, if any of *u*, *uc*, *y*, *yc*, *d* are not scalar but a vector, your result will be a vector as well.

Otherwise there seems to be nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply, all inputs are scalar. i edited the question with the errors i get.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use variables within your function `myfun` that are defined outside the function scope and thus not visible. I recommend to follow Bill's advice and figure out if all your variables in the erroneous statement are well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

read the documentation of fsolve: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fsolve.html

it states:

> `fun` 
>   The nonlinear system of equations to solve. `fun` is a function that accepts a vector `x` and returns a vector `F`, the nonlinear equations evaluated at `x`.

Obviously your function `myfun` doesn't handle vector input.
You can solve this by adding the following construction inside your function (and of course change it to your needs/your parameters):

```
function out = myfun(in)
    if ~isscalar(in)
        % assuming it's a matrix or vector
        out = reshape(arrayfun(@myfun,in(:)),size(in));
    else
        % your actual function execution statements
        out = dostuffon(in);
    end
end
```

or properly vectorize your function (if that's possible)